# Headphones only work correcly when plugged halfway

Tags: linux, debian, audio, cinnamon

My headphones are working some kind of strange.

The sound is very low even when set to maximum, and the speech is almost unhearable. When I listen to music I can't hear speech as well as when watching movies. Also there is some kind of strange noise.

But, when I try to unplug my headphones halfway everything works perfectly.

The problem is definitely not in headphones because I tested them on Windows.

I use Debian 8 with Cinnamon 2.6.13 on it.

UPD: The same situation on Linux Mint(on the same machine). Looks like this is some kind of drivers problems.

Comment: mixer problems and/or mono mode I suspect...

Comment: *“Tested them on Windows”* – on the same computer? Is it a normal TRS jack (stereo only - three bands on the jack plug), or a TRRS jack (headset with mic - four bands on the jack plug).

Comment: @Sukminder Yes on the same computer and yes they have TRS jack.

Comment: Older sound cards had 3,4,5,6,7 jacks out the back.  Modern sound cards use fewer jacks by "intelligently" switching. But this may be controlled by drivers and OS settings. Perhaps the sound cards is configured for mono or something else?

Answer (score -1):

that sounds like a hardware problem, that jack is messed up, try a different pair of headphones if you have any laying around. if they do the same then I'd say yep, female jack is deff messed up,  it is the connections, old school it'd be mono plug into sterio jack incompatibility issues. if you plug it is all the way with that pair you're using try wiggling the wire to see if it has a short in it.

Comment: If it is a hardware problem, why do they work on Windows on the same PC?

Comment: I must have sneezed when reading, and missed that part.